# Incrementing itertools.imap without reading to object in Python for performance

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-itertools

I am trying to look at the pixels from the centre of a screenshot. I am using PngPy to read the screenshot, and want to get to the pixels quickly.

```
import png
import itertools

r=png.Reader("myfile.png")
direct = r.asRGBA8()

bytesIter = direct[2] # returns itertools.imap object - 
                      # see https://pythonhosted.org/pypng/png.html
height = direct[1]

count=0
for row in bytesIter:
    if count >= (height/2):
        print "Half way"
        break
    count+=1

print count
```

**Is there anyway to increment the iterator without reading it to a new object?** 
This operation is taking 2 seconds for 768x1280 png (which does have an Alpha channel) on a fast workstation.

Comment: so where is `itertools.imap` ? how you use it ?

Comment: bytesIter is a itertools.imap object. When I get to the half way mark I will read the contents of row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`consume` recipe](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) from itertools:

```
from itertools import islice
from collections import deque

def consume(iterator, n):
    "Advance the iterator n-steps ahead. If n is none, consume entirely."
    # Use functions that consume iterators at C speed.
    if n is None:
        # feed the entire iterator into a zero-length deque
        deque(iterator, maxlen=0)
    else:
        # advance to the empty slice starting at position n
        next(islice(iterator, n, n), None)
```

So, in your case:

```
consume(bytesIter, height/2)
```